# Puppet: stdlib installed but not available in namespace?

Tags: namespaces, include, std, puppet

as a puppet newbie, I have a problem including the stdlib plugin

I would like to use stdlib's file_line, thus I try to include stdlib and call it

```rb
class service_mon
{
  include stdlib
  file_line 
  {
    "${name}_services": path=> ...
  }
}
```

However, I get an error message, that stdlib cannot been found

> err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on
>   SERVER: Could not find class stdlib for my.node.name at
>   /etc/puppet/workspace/dev/src/modules/mymanifest/manifests/deploy.pp:87
>   on node my.node.name

which makes me wonder since stdlib should be installed(?) ...or?

```
puppet module install puppetlabs-stdli

puppet module list
/etc/puppet/modules
└── puppetlabs-stdlib (v4.2.2)
/usr/share/puppet/modules (no modules installed)

puppet config print modulepath
/etc/puppet/modules:/usr/share/puppet/modules
```

So, I guess in principle all necessary files are 'there' but how can I convince Puppet to include stdlib as well?

Comment: chown -R puppet:puppet /etc/puppet/

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I seem to be running into the exact same issue. :-/

Comment: Hi Christopher - unfortunately I have not yet managed to get it running satisfactorily -- and 'postponed' it by using a small shell script to do the work I hoped I could solve with stdlib :-/

Comment: I had to explicitly provide the modules path using modulePath option in my puppet file apply command in terminal: 

```bash
 puppet apply 0-the_sky_is_the_limit_not.pp --modulepath /etc/puppet/code/modules
```

Answer (score 4):

Puppet modules do not work like java modules - `include stdlib` would only make sense if there actually was a `class stdlib` in the module which did something useful, which is not the case.

*Note:* Many Puppet modules **do** have such a class that serves as the central entry point, but `stdlib` is a notable exception.

You can use the parser functions from stdlib by just calling them. As for the types, those just become available to Puppet if

- the module is installed inside your `$modulepath` and
- you have `pluginsync` enabled on your agents

You can use `file_line` without any ado.